# How to make system restore point that will not be deleted after newer points created?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, operating-systems, system-restore

*I use Windows 8.1*

System restore deletes old point when creates a new one. I want to manually create a new point that will not be deleted after the creation of newer points. How to do that?

Comment: "System restore deletes old point when creates a new one" not true, it deletes oldest restore points when the selected size of disk space is used up, this can be changed to keep more restore points.

Comment: @Moab So, you mean that I can disable deleting old points? How to do that?

Comment: No, all you can do is increase the amount of disk space to use for restore points, this will allow it to keep more of them, no way to make it infinite.

Comment: You cannot create a permanent restore point. The system was never designed for that. The further back you go the more likely the restore will fail or you end up in a worse situation than before the restore. If you need something permanent you would be far better off maintaining image backups to another drive. Far more reliable and you can make as many backups going as far back as you wish.

Comment: If, for example, you create a system restore point in January that you want to keep for a long time,  and then in August your restore point storage space is filling up, you can use [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/) to delete the restore points from February through July, to free up space, so the system won’t delete the one from January.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the paid version of Macrium Reflect for many years.
From personal experience I know it works better than Restore Points.
There is a free version.
They have good support & a forum.

[Free Version of Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. This is a pretty good first attempt at a software recommendation. For more details please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/a/5330) paying particular attention to the items in `bold`. If necessary, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1346199/edit) so it follows the guidelines.